# how can change text - alignment to the left in UIAlertAction in swift

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

How can I change the text-alignment for `UIAlertAction` title in Action sheet to the left side in swift language?

below is my code :

```
let alertController = UIAlertController()
        let alertImage = UIAlertAction(title: "Image", style: .default, handler: nil)
        let alertVideo = UIAlertAction(title: "Video", style: .default, handler: nil)

        let alertFile = UIAlertAction(title: "File", style: .default, handler: nil)
        let alertCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        // Here is the key thing!
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .left

        let messageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: "Video",
            attributes: [
                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline),
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.black
            ]
        )

        // add icon to the left alert action
        let image = UIImage(named: "video")
        alertVideo.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
        // align text in the alertAction
        alertVideo.setValue(UIColor.black, forKey: "titleTextColor")
        alertVideo.setValue(messageText, forKey: "attributedTitle")

        alertController.addAction(alertImage)
        alertController.addAction(alertVideo)
        alertController.addAction(alertFile)
        alertController.addAction(alertCancel)

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I get the error message is

```
[<UIAlertAction 0x7a6eb760> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key attributedTitle
```

How can I fix this issue so I can change text alignment for the Alert Action in action sheet

thank you very much

Comment: I'm 90% sure you'd need to do a custom alert view for this because system alerts views have their default styling hard-wired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can't make this using default UIAlertController.

But you can try to use custom framework, like OKAlertController.

It has extended customisation

https://github.com/OlehKulykov/OKAlertController